# pbkdf2 computation not consistent between C# and JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, encryption, pbkdf2

Hi my question is I've Encrypted a password with crypto.pbkdf2 on windows azure server side Javascript I'm pretty sure that there is a public library which you can look up. The problem is I'm trying to encrypt the same password in C# on my system because I want the credentials to be universal but despite using Rfc2898DeriveBytes and the salt generated the first time I'm not able to get back to the same hashed password.

Thank you for your help :)

```
function hash(text, salt, callback) {
  crypto.pbkdf2(text, salt, iterations, bytes, function(err, derivedKey){
    if (err) { callback(err); }
    else {
      var h = new Buffer(derivedKey).toString('base64');
      callback(null, h);
    }
  });
}
```

And the C# code:

```
byte[] salt = Convert.FromBase64String(user.salt);
using (var deriveBytes = new System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, 1000))
{
  byte[] newKey = deriveBytes.GetBytes(32);

  // user is the user object drawn from the database in existence
  if (Convert.ToBase64String(newKey).Equals(user.password))
  {
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Request.Form["username"], false);
  }
}
```

hex generated by C# = 3lRSQF5ImYlQg20CGFy2iGUpWfdP5TD0eq2cTHhLono=

hex generated by JS = w4PDh8K6YMKGwr3DgcObRsOsFFUgDMOJw5PCnkdAwrTCgcOOV8OCKMKFdcKRwrLCqMK2VA==

Salt generated by JS and used at both = /Ij0hgDsvAC1DevM7xkdGUVlozdCxXVd0lgfK2xEh2A=

All the above info is in base64 format

Another thing that might be useful

```
item.salt = new Buffer(crypto.randomBytes(bytes)).toString('base64'); crypto.pbkdf2(text, salt, iterations, bytes, function(err, derivedKey){
```

which means the JS function accepts a string

Comment: You should show your encryption and decryption code for both languages.

Comment: Thanks Jim, and matthew code samples are in :) thanks

Comment: @Jim The post you referenced specifically allows for tags in titles when the tag is used in a normal conversational tone.

Comment: @user3053234 What is iterations set to in your js code? Just guessing at possibilities here, but if it's not 1000 then that could be your problem.

Comment: Also, I can't seem to tell what .NET is going to use for an encoding if password is a string. Assuming you haven't already, it might be good to convert the string to bytes using ASCII (I'm pretty sure that's the encoding js is using).

Comment: CrazyCasta the iteration for JS is 1000 as well

Comment: @CrazyCasta .NET uses UTF-8 for PBKDF2, backwards compatible with ASCII. This is according to sources within Mono, who tested their implementation with that of .NET.

Comment: It seems we are suck regarding the program code. Could you post the output pBKDF2 as well (using a test password, of course)? Try and use hexadecimals or just text if the output is already encoded.

Comment: I sure can give me a min, btw ty for your help :)

Comment: One problem that I can see here is that for the javascript implementation, you never say that you want to retrieve a 32 byte digest

Comment: Hi Matthew, I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough but in the 
crypto.pbkdf2(text, salt, iterations, bytes function the iteration = 1000 and bytes = 32

Answer (score 0):

> I want the credentials to be universal but despite using Rfc2898DeriveBytes and the salt generated the first time I'm not able to get back to the same hashed password.

The obvious stuff is hash algorithm, salt, and iteration count. Can you confirm (for both languages):

1. the hash algorithm
2. the salt
3. the iteration count

The non-obvious is the encoding of the password and possibly salt. I included the salt because its often stored as a string.

To keep it portable among languages, you should use UTF-8. That's because you could encounter a default encoding, a UTF16-BE, UTF16-LE or any number of other encoding.

In C#, the setup would be:

```
byte[] utf8_salt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt);
byte[] utf8_pass = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
```

You would then pass `utf8_salt` and `utf8_pass` to the `PBKDF2` function.

I don't know how to do the same in Javascript.

Comment: I tried that but didn't help sadly I do appreciate your help tho. The password sizes are different for some reason if that helps

Comment: user3053234 - I don't mean to sound argumentative, but the source code you provided indicates otherwise :)

Comment: No offense taken, I'm baffled I think its some encoding it uses or something because I'm not getting the full 32 bytes from this silly C#..

Comment: `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` uses HMAC-SHA1, so you will only get 20 bytes from it. See [Rfc2898DeriveBytes Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). What does the Javascript code use by default?

Answer (score 0):

Alright kids daddy has figured out the answer.. took long enough..

```
Buffer(encodedPassword, 'binary').toString('base64')
```

on Javascript side will suffice now the tutorial I looked at was clearly not accurate.. the 'binary' was missing.

Thank you all for the help :)

and happy new year